# Chrome push notifications. Message identification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, push

While i send notification to the client, i have a some data:

```
$> curl --header "Authorization: key=$key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"$subs\"]}"    
{"multicast_id":5959734605210485936,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1454898928592704%592683fbf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

This is **multicast_id** and **message_id** params.

My question is: how i can get one of (or both) these params from ServiceWorker script?

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
  ...
  // I need something like that:
  msgid = event.message_id;
  m_castid = event.multicast_id;
  ...
});
```

In other words, i need of an any possible way to determine message inside ServiceWorker script.

Thanks in advance,

With best regards,

Nikolai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I don`t know how to get the message ID, but found how to identify your subscription:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    ...
    self.registration.pushManager
      .getSubscription()
      .then( function( subscription ) 
    {
        var registrationId = subscription.endpoint.split('/');
        registrationId = registrationId[ registrationId.length - 1 ];
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

May be it will be useful for somebody.